# Create new array based on comparison between two array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Suppose I have two array of Object as,

```
let oldBookDetails = [
    {'name':'Harry pottar','amount':10, is_modified: false},
    {'name':'LOTR','amount':20, is_modified: false},
    {'name':'dune','amount':15, is_modified: false}
]

let newBookDetails = [
    {'name':'Harry pottar','amount':15},
    {'name':'LOTR','amount':20},
    {'name':'HR','amount':15}
]

let bookModified = []
```

I want to create new array of Object by comparing newBookDetails with oldBookDetails,

and check if any name is removed newDetails, don't push into the bookModified array,

if amount has been changed then push newBookDetails object into bookModified with is_modified: true and if newBookDetails amount is same push into bookModified array with is_modified:false.

For this I tried as:

```
newBookDetails.forEach((el) => {

    oldBookDetails.forEach((ele) => {

        if(Object.values(el).indexOf(el.name) > -1) {
            if(el.amount === ele.amount) {
                bookModified.push(el)
            }else if(el.amount != ele.amount) {
                el.is_modified = true
                bookModified.push(el)
            }
        } else if(Object.values(el).indexOf(el.name) === -1) {
            //this loops as all are not equal....i am stuck from this part.
        }
    })
})
```

Expected O/P :

console.log(newBookDetails)

```
[
    {'name':'Harry pottar','amount':15, is_modified: true},
    {'name':'LOTR','amount':20, is_modified: false},
    {'name':'HR','amount':15, is_modified: true}
]
```

If anyone needs any further information please do let me know.

Comment: `Object.values(el).indexOf(el.name) > -1` is checking if the current `el` object has a name propety value that is in `el` - this will alaways be true, as you're grabbing a value from your object, and then checking if that value is in that same object. You probably want to compare names from both objects: `ele.name === el.name`. Your `else if` can also be made into just `else` (or even removed entirely)

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/1zLtu9qc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `map()` and `find()`:

**map()** on the second array and try to **find** the book in the first one using property name.
If not found pass in modified **true**, else check the amount and pass modified value accordingly.

```js
let oldBookDetails = [
  { 'name': 'Harry pottar', 'amount': 10, is_modified: false },
  { 'name': 'LOTR', 'amount': 20, is_modified: false },
  { 'name': 'dune', 'amount': 15, is_modified: false }
];

let newBookDetails = [
  { 'name': 'Harry pottar', 'amount': 15 },
  { 'name': 'LOTR', 'amount': 20 },
  { 'name': 'HR', 'amount': 15 }
];

let bookModified = newBookDetails.map((x) => {
  let foundBook = oldBookDetails.find(old => old.name === x.name);
  if (foundBook) {
    if (foundBook.amount !== x.amount)
      return { ...x, is_modified: true };
    else
      return { ...x, is_modified: false };
  }
  else
    return { ...x, is_modified: true };
});
console.log(bookModified);
```

Comment: My solution: https://jsfiddle.net/1zLtu9qc/

Comment: Edited the answer with `...` operator. Missed that part

Comment: Actually I have one more query should I ask new question or can I update in the same.::

My query::Create a variable string to keep note of whether amount has been reduced or increased or removed and for which book.

Ex: 'Owner removed Book dune'

Comment: @SushantRad see my anser for that check. I have incooperated that aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with below snippet

```
newBookDetails.forEach(newBook => {
  let found = false;
  oldBookDetails.forEach(oldBook => {
    if (oldBook.name === newBook.name) {
      if (oldBook.amount === newBook.amount) {
        bookModified.push({
          'name': newBook.name,
          'amount': newBook.amount,
          is_modified: false
        })
      } else {
        bookModified.push({
          'name': newBook.name,
          'amount': newBook.amount,
          is_modified: true
        })
      }
      found = true;
    }
  })
  if (!found) {
    bookModified.push({
      'name': newBook.name,
      'amount': newBook.amount,
      is_modified: true
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Here's a shorter way: https://jsfiddle.net/1zLtu9qc/

Answer (score 0):

```js
let oldBookDetails = [
    {'name':'Harry pottar','amount':10, is_modified: false},
    {'name':'LOTR','amount':20, is_modified: false},
    {'name':'dune','amount':15, is_modified: false}
]

let newBookDetails = [
    {'name':'Harry pottar','amount':15},
    {'name':'LOTR','amount':20},
    {'name':'HR','amount':15}
]

let bookModified = oldBookDetails
  .filter((oldBookDetail) => newBookDetails.findIndex((bookDetails) => bookDetails.name === oldBookDetail.name) > -1)
  .map((oldBookDetails) => {
  const newDetails = newBookDetails.find((bookDetails) => bookDetails.name === oldBookDetails);
  return {...oldBookDetails, ...newDetails};
});

console.log(bookModified);
```

Could be done better though, if you spend more time in optimizing and sharpening

Comment: Wrong result. Right way: https://jsfiddle.net/1zLtu9qc/

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` will help you to generate the new array as per your requirement.

Logic

- Loop through `newBookDetails` array.
- Check if node from `newBookDetails` is present in `oldBookDetails`
- If no return the newBook node with `is_modified` as `true`
- If yes. return the node with `is_modified` value as a boolean that compare the new book and old book price.
- To find the removed book, filter the `oldBookDetails` array and check nodes that are not prtesent in `newBookDetails`

```js
const oldBookDetails = [ {'name':'Harry pottar','amount':10, is_modified: false}, {'name':'LOTR','amount':20, is_modified: false}, {'name':'dune','amount':15, is_modified: false}];
const newBookDetails = [ {'name':'Harry pottar','amount':15}, {'name':'LOTR','amount':20}, {'name':'HR','amount':15} ];
const bookModified = newBookDetails.map((node) => {
  const oldBookNode = oldBookDetails.find((item) => item.name === node.name);
  if (oldBookNode) {
    return { ...node, is_modified: oldBookNode.amount !==  node.amount }
  } else {
    return { ...node, is_modified: true };
  }
});
const removedBooks = oldBookDetails.filter((book) => !newBookDetails.find((node) => node.name === book.name));
console.log(bookModified);
console.log(removedBooks);
```